# Hibernate (suspend to disk) without filesystems sync

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, hibernate

I am debugging an issue with hibernation on my system, and (long story short) it boils down to [hibernate.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/kernel/power/hibernate.c) invoking filesystem sync ([ksys_sync_helper](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/kernel/power/hibernate.c#L735)) before freezing the processes and then subsequently moving on to the next stages of hibernation.

My goal in this exercise is to skip the `ksys_sync_helper()` call. This is because the block devices that get synced might need to be suspended before hibernation.

This would be easy with suspend to RAM - there's a flag in the kernel that drives that, and [suspend.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/kernel/power/suspend.c#L568-L572) respects that flag, allowing users to skip the sync. This is explained nicely in the relevant [patch](https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/linux-pm/patch/d34ad8b1-8c0a-99d9-dc3e-319600c0bc39@freesources.org/).

Is there any reason why this is not configurable for hibernation? In particular, if I was to patch the kernel and get rid of that call, what is the risk? I do intend to call sync *immediately* before triggering hibernation, but admittedly, the window between sync and hibernation will be somewhat longer.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? Writing data to a disk that ius "suspended" (as you say)? Why not write the data (unmount, maybe) before suspending? It looks as if you are making the problem worse.

Comment: It's the sync that's trying to write the data to a suspended disk (luks suspended, to be precise), which is why I want to disable it. The hibernation image gets written to a different block device entirely. Alas, it's the root partition, so unmounting it is not an option.

Comment: What sense does it make to have a hibernation image (that allows you to power off) when you have unwritten "dirty" data in RAM? You are doing something *very* strange.

Comment: Which is why I intend to run `sync` just before suspending the partition, but not after. Very strange things have a slight chance of bringing useful results, which is what this research project is ultimately about.